# How can I use PHP to check if a directory is empty?

Tags: php, directory

I am using the following script to read a directory. If there is no file in the directory it should say empty. The problem is, it just keeps saying the directory is empty even though there ARE files inside and vice versa.

```php
<?php
$pid = $_GET["prodref"];
$dir = '/assets/'.$pid.'/v';
$q   = (count(glob("$dir/*")) === 0) ? 'Empty' : 'Not empty';
    
if ($q=="Empty") 
    echo "the folder is empty"; 
else
    echo "the folder is NOT empty";
?>
```

Comment: It's just a typo in your if statement. Use == (compare) instead of the single = (assign).

Answer (score 155, accepted):

It seems that you need `scandir` instead of glob, as glob can't see unix hidden files.

```
<?php
$pid = basename($_GET["prodref"]); //let's sanitize it a bit
$dir = "/assets/$pid/v";

if (is_dir_empty($dir)) {
  echo "the folder is empty"; 
}else{
  echo "the folder is NOT empty";
}

function is_dir_empty($dir) {
  return (count(scandir($dir)) == 2);
}
```

Note that this code is not the summit of efficiency, as it's unnecessary to read all the files only to tell if directory is empty. So, the better version would be

```
function dir_is_empty($dir) {
  $handle = opendir($dir);
  while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
    if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
      closedir($handle);
      return false;
    }
  }
  closedir($handle);
  return true;
}
```

By the way, do not use *words* to substitute *boolean* values. The very purpose of the latter is to tell you if something empty or not. An

```
a === b
```

expression already returns `Empty` or `Non Empty` in terms of programming language, `false` or `true` respectively - so, you can use the very result in control structures like `IF()` without any intermediate values

Comment: I think both our code is wrong because I removed all files from the folder and it still says the folder is not empty... is there a way to check for hidden files like thumbs.db etc in linux??

Comment: I think the FTP folder is say .. and . in the file is empty. How can I check if and remove the .. and thumbs.db etc??

Comment: glob doesn't support linux hidden files. if you want them you have to go for openir solution like in the deleted answer

Comment: it seems you need scandir instead of glob.

Comment: The code won't work. None of them. If I have files inside, it says "the folder is NOT empty" and if I removed the files.. it says "the folder is NOT empty".. either way it won't detect

Comment: it works for me. try to simplify your code, removing GET part. debug it. var_dump(scandir($dir))

Comment: When I remove GET no error appears. The page is white - blank.

Comment: DEBUG IT! sensible! not by just removing code parts at random but reducing it without losing productivity

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand you. The folder will always contain two files (one .swf and one .jpg file) I have tried different browsers, moved the files around etc and deleted them... what is this debug?

Comment: Do create testing environment. create empty directory in the same folder where script is. make `$dir = 'testfolder';` manually. then run this code. debug is printing out as much information as possible to see what is going wrong. `$dir = 'testfolder';var_dump(scan_dir($dir));` will tell you what is in this directory

Comment: Don’t forget to `closedir($handle)` afterwards.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks. much appreciated your effort. +1 up vote.

Comment: What is missing in the answer is the fact that there are 3 possible hidden files in a directory. The files '.' and '..' are always there, on Windows and yes also on Mac. On a Mac you may have the file '.DS_Store'. This file is created when the directory has have content. What does this mean?
Well simply count the files is not an option because it maybe 2 or 3 files on Mac. So you have to loop over all files in the directory and test for the fileName. See my answer below.

Comment: is there a reason you chose loose comparison for the `.` & `..`?

Answer (score 84):

I think using the [FilesystemIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.filesystemiterator.php) should be the fastest and easiest way:

```
// PHP 5 >= 5.3.0
$iterator = new \FilesystemIterator($dir);
$isDirEmpty = !$iterator->valid();
```

Or using class member access on instantiation:

```
// PHP 5 >= 5.4.0
$isDirEmpty = !(new \FilesystemIterator($dir))->valid();
```

This works because a new `FilesystemIterator` will initially point to the first file in the folder - if there are no files in the folder, `valid()` will return `false`. (see documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.valid.php).)

As pointed out by abdulmanov.ilmir, optionally check if the directory exists before using the `FileSystemIterator` because otherwise it'll throw an `UnexpectedValueException`.

Comment: Mmm... tingling in my loins for this one.

Comment: You should consider that if `$dir` is not exists then an exception will be thrown.

Comment: Short and sweet.

Answer (score 13):

I found a quick solution

```
<?php
  $dir = 'directory'; // dir path assign here
  echo (count(glob("$dir/*")) === 0) ? 'Empty' : 'Not empty';
?>
```

Comment: The solution I use in php 5.2 for simple case.

Comment: Beware that glob does not see hidden files. A directory containing ie ".htaccess" will be treated as empty with this code

Answer (score 7):

For a object oriented approach using the [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) from the [Standard PHP Library (SPL)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php).

```
<?php

namespace My\Folder;

use RecursiveDirectoryIterator;

class FileHelper
{
    /**
     * @param string $dir
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function isEmpty($dir)
    {
        $di = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
        return iterator_count($di) === 0;
    }
}
```

No need to make an instance of your `FileHelper` whenever you need it, you can access this static method wherever you need it like this:

```
FileHelper::isEmpty($dir);
```

The `FileHelper` class can be extended with other useful methods for copying, deleting, renaming, etc.

There is no need to check the validity of the directory inside the method because if it is invalid the constructor of the `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` will throw an `UnexpectedValueException` which that covers that part sufficiently.

Answer (score 6):

This is a very old thread, but I thought I'd give my ten cents.  The other solutions didn't work for me.

Here is my solution:

```
function is_dir_empty($dir) {
    foreach (new DirectoryIterator($dir) as $fileInfo) {
        if($fileInfo->isDot()) continue;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Short and sweet.  Works like a charm.

Answer (score 5):

use

```
if ($q == "Empty")
```

instead of

```
if ($q="Empty")
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
<?php
$dirPath = "Add your path here";

$destdir = $dirPath;

$handle = opendir($destdir);
$c = 0;
while ($file = readdir($handle)&& $c<3) {
    $c++;
}

if ($c>2) {
    print "Not empty";
} else {
    print "Empty";
} 

?>
```

Comment: Thanks! I wrote it quite quickly and its my first post here @Piotr Nowicki

Comment: Sure mate, it's just my civic duty ;-) Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 5):

I used:

```
if(is_readable($dir)&&count(scandir($dir))==2) ... //then the dir is empty
```

Answer (score 4):

Probably because of assignment operator in `if` statement.

Change:

```
if ($q="Empty")
```

To:

```
if ($q=="Empty")
```

Answer (score 4):

@ Your Common Sense

I think your performant example could be more performant using strict comparison:

```
function is_dir_empty($dir) {
  if (!is_readable($dir)) return null; 
  $handle = opendir($dir);
  while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
    if ($entry !== '.' && $entry !== '..') { // <-- better use strict comparison here
      closedir($handle); // <-- always clean up! Close the directory stream
      return false;
    }
  }
  closedir($handle); // <-- always clean up! Close the directory stream
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Good point regarding clean up: The `return false` case is not taking care of it ;-)

Comment: @BeatChristen Thx for the hint! Fixed it.

Comment: What I don't understand is why you say that it is better to use strict comparision when comparing to "." and "..". The readdir() function will always return a string (or the false) so I don't see the point. I'd also like to add that cleaning up after yourself is indeed always a good idea, one would think that after return when the $handle variable goes out of scope, closedir() would happen automatically but I just wrote a little test program, and it doesn't. Which is strange because other stuff, like flock do happen automatically.

Comment: @AndréFiedler You are a genius, brilliant and responsible person. In all other answers, they first calculating total number of files and then checking if count > 0.  But if a directory contains even one file, it is not empty.

Answer (score 3):

Function `count` usage maybe slow on big array. `isset` is ever faster

This will work properly on PHP >= 5.4.0 (see Changelog [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php))

```
function dir_is_empty($path){ //$path is realpath or relative path

    $d = scandir($path, SCANDIR_SORT_NONE ); // get dir, without sorting improve performace (see Comment below). 

    if ($d){

        // avoid "count($d)", much faster on big array. 
        // Index 2 means that there is a third element after ".." and "."

        return !isset($d[2]); 
    }

    return false; // or throw an error
}
```

Otherwise, using @Your Common Sense solution it's better for avoid load file list on RAM

Thanks and vote up to @soger too, to improve this answer using `SCANDIR_SORT_NONE` option.

Comment: As long as we worry about performance, you may want to add the  SCANDIR_SORT_NONE parameter too.

Answer (score 2):

Just correct your code like this:

```
<?php
    $pid = $_GET["prodref"];
    $dir = '/assets/'.$pid.'/v';
    $q = count(glob("$dir/*")) == 0;

    if ($q) {
        echo "the folder is empty"; 
    } else {
        echo "the folder is NOT empty";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Even an empty directory contains 2 files `.` and `..`, one is a link to the current directory and the second to the parent. Thus, you can use code like this:

```
$files = scandir("path to directory/");
if(count($files) == 2) {
  //do something if empty
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

I use this method in my Wordpress CSV 2 POST plugin.

```
    public function does_folder_contain_file_type( $path, $extension ){
        $all_files  = new RecursiveIteratorIterator( new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $path ) );

        $html_files = new RegexIterator( $all_files, '/\.'.$extension.'/' );  

        foreach( $html_files as $file) {
            return true;// a file with $extension was found
        }   

    return false;// no files with our extension found
}
```

It works by specific extension but is easily changed to suit your needs by removing "new RegexIterator(" line. Count $all_files.

```
    public function does_folder_contain_file_type( $path, $extension ){
        $all_files  = new RecursiveIteratorIterator( new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $path ) );

        return count( $all_files );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently, although, the highest up-voted answer did not really work for me, hence, I had to come up with a similar solution. and again this may also not be the most efficient way to go about the problem,

I created a function like so

```
function is_empty_dir($dir)
   {
       if (is_dir($dir))
       {
            $objects = scandir($dir);
            foreach ($objects as $object)
            {
                if ($object != "." && $object != "..")
                {
                    if (filetype($dir."/".$object) == "dir")
                    {
                         return false;
                    } else { 
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            reset($objects);
            return true;
       }
```

and used it to check for empty dricetory like so

```
if(is_empty_dir($path)){
            rmdir($path);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
function isEmptyDir($dir)
{
    return (($files = @scandir($dir)) && count($files) <= 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first question is when is a directory empty? In a directory there are 2 files the '.' and '..'. 

Next to that on a Mac there maybe the file '.DS_Store'. This file is created when some kind of content is added to the directory. If these 3 files are in the directory you may say the directory is empty.
So to test if a directory is empty (without testing if $dir is a directory):

```
function isDirEmpty( $dir ) {
  $count = 0;
  foreach (new DirectoryIterator( $dir ) as $fileInfo) {
     if ( $fileInfo->isDot() || $fileInfo->getBasename() == '.DS_Store' ) {
        continue;
     }
     $count++;
  }
  return ($count === 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Your Common Sense,@Enyby

Some improvement of your code:

```
function dir_is_empty($dir) {
    $handle = opendir($dir);
    $result = true;
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            $result = false;
            break 2;
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
    return $result;
}
```

I use a variable for storing the result and set it to true.
If the directory is empty the only files that are returned are . and .. (on a linux server, you could extend the condition for mac if you need to) and therefore the condition is true.
Then the value of result is set to false and break 2 exit the if and the while loop so the next statement executed is closedir.
Therefore the while loop will only have 3 circles before it will end regardless if the directory is empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
$is_folder_empty = function(string $folder) : bool {
    if (!is_dir($folder))
        return TRUE;

    // This wont work on non linux OS.
    return is_null(shell_exec("ls {$folder}"));
};
$is_folder_empty2 = function(string $folder) : bool {
    if (!is_dir($folder))
        return TRUE;
    
    // Empty folders have two files in it. Single dot and
    // double dot.
    return count(scandir($folder)) === 2;
};

var_dump($is_folder_empty('/tmp/demo'));
var_dump($is_folder_empty2('/tmp/demo'));
```