# How to check if folder has at least 1 file in php

Tags: php

I want to check if a folder has at least 1 file. 
I am now using this to check if a folder is empty but this also checks if there is a subfolder in it.

```
if (count(glob($dir.'/*')) === 0 ) {}
```

And I only want to check for files in it

Comment: use this solution and check for `3` instead of `2` : http://stackoverflow.com/a/7497848/2815635

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497733/how-can-use-php-to-check-if-a-directory-is-empty

Comment: @Rishi This is also not the right solution. When i have per example 5 subfolders in it but no file it says the folder is not empty!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it by using `opendir` and `readdir`

```
function check_file($dir) {
    $result = false;
    if($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while(!$result && ($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            $result = $file !== "." && $file !== ".." && !is_dir($file);
        }

        closedir($dh);
    }

    return $result;
}

$dir="/var/www/html/jkjkj/";// your path here
echo check_file($dir);// return 1 if file found otherwise empty
```

Comment: `$result = $file !== "." && $file !== ".." && !is_dir($file);`

Comment: @DarkBee yaa correct . It will check child is not a directory!!

Comment: @Saty this gives me  1 when there ia a file or a subdirectory in it. It should give only 1 if there is a file in it

Comment: Yaa it will fulfill  requirement to check  at least 1 file inside folder

Comment: So i need a way to check if there are only FILES in a folder; not subdirectories