# PHP: The fastest way to check if the directory is empty?

Tags: php, php-7.2

On Stack Overflow there are several answers to the question of how to check if the directory is empty,  but which is the fastest, which way is the most effective?

---

**Answer 1:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/7497848/4437206

```
function dir_is_empty($dir) {
  $handle = opendir($handle);
  while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
    if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
      closedir($handle); // <= I added this
      return FALSE;
    }
  }

  closedir($handle); // <= I added this
  return TRUE;
}
```

---

**Answer 2:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/18856880/4437206

```
$isDirEmpty = !(new \FilesystemIterator($dir))->valid();
```

---

**Answer 3:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/19243116/4437206

```
$dir = 'directory'; // dir path assign here
echo (count(glob("$dir/*")) === 0) ? 'Empty' : 'Not empty';
```

---

**Or,** there is a completely different way which is faster and more effective than these three above?

As for the Answer 1, please note that I added `closedir($handle);`, but I'm not sure if that's necessary (?).

**EDIT:** Initially I added `closedir($dir);` instead of `closedir($handle);`, but I corrected that as [@duskwuff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/149341/duskwuff) stated in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50689794/4437206).

Comment: Who cares? Readability is far more important.

Comment: Did you run a benchmark?

Comment: @arkascha I care.

Comment: what about the other ways?

Comment: Unless the file system functions have changed, you could also just do a `count(scandir()) > 2` check in the function.

Comment: @Jhecht That's conceptually similar to the `glob()` solution, and will also perform poorly on large directories.

Comment: I'm unaware how PHP handles those sorts of things internally so if you know more of the actual implementation to `scandir` then I'll trust you on it. I was just saying it was another option.

Comment: @smith Noooo. Launching a new process is _much_ more "expensive", and I can't think of any single command which would do the job in a nondestructive fashion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `opendir()`/`readdir()` and `FilesystemIterator` approaches are both conceptually equivalent, and perform identical system calls (as tested on PHP 7.2 running under Linux). There's no fundamental reason why either one would be faster than the other, so I would recommend that you run benchmarks if you need to microoptimize.

The approach using `glob()` will perform worse. `glob()` returns an array of all the filenames in the directory; constructing that array can take some time. If there are many files in the directory, it will perform *much* worse, as it must iterate through the entire contents of the directory.

Using `glob()` will also give incorrect results in a number of situations:

- If `$dir` is a directory name which contains certain special characters, including `*`, `?`, and `[`/`]`
- If `$dir` contains only dotfiles (i.e, filenames starting with `.`)

> As for the Answer 1, please note that I added `closedir($dir);`, but I'm not sure if that's necessary (?).

It's a good idea, but you've implemented it incorrectly. The directory handle that needs to be closed is `$handle`, not `$dir`.